# Angular styles remain after exiting component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular project with different components, containers and a router. Let's say my 2 pages are `/login` and `/home`. The problem is that I have some styles in `/login` which after routing to `/home` still remain there and break my styles in `/home`. The solution I thought of so far is to add a parent div to both pages and to add all the styles inside the div. It works but I want to ask if anyone had same problem and found a better/more concise solution. Thank you.

Comment: Is `/home` in anyway child or subcomponent of `/login` ? Also please check if you have any global styles in your `style.css` file which could be affecting both. Last, I would also suggest to check the `ViewEncapsulation` strategy.

Comment: I have checked that some styles coming in `/home` are from `/login` for some reason. They are both "top level", so no one is child of another. +1 for ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Solved my issue

Answer (score -1):

some classes maybe used in components, for example in login you have content class and in home you have used same class, it will used the attributed for the class, plz check inspect element and check where the styles are come from? see From any file it's? and Where you have used it

Comment: The styles in `/home` come from `/login` and there aren't any components that are used in both classes